# How to use PlaceFilter with Place Picker?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I've started making an app and my intention is to use a Place Picker UI Widget to display a list of only Hospitals. I can't seem to find a proper solution to this anywhere. Is it possible to do so? if not, what are the alternatives?